# Installing Maven on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3: no Maven version displayed

Tags: maven, redhat

I installed OpenJDK 11 and Maven `3.8.1` on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3` as follows:

```
yum install java-11-openjdk
cd /opt
wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz
mv apache-maven-3.8.1 /opt/maven
```

Then I created the `maven.sh` script to declare JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables as follows:

```
vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

# added the following content:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Reloade the shell with `source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh`.

When checking the installed Maven version, it is not displayed, just the Java's one:

```
mvn -v


Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.10.0.9-4.el8_3.x86_64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I hoped to see something like:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
...
```

What am I missing? Or everything is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here. I have tried almost the same steps and it worked for me.

Adding those steps below

1. sudo yum install java-11-openjdk
2. sudo wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz
3. sudo tar xvf apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz
4. sudo ln -s apache-maven-3.8.1 maven
5. sudo vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

added the below

```
export JAVA_HOME={provide the path, where your jdk is}
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

6. source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
7. mvn -version

[screenshot of maven version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRwgd.png)

Hopefully, this will work for you!